# Pentaho - Execute a Kettle Transformation remotely using Java

Tags: java, pentaho, kettle

I am executing My Jobs/ Transformation using Java API and I am able to do it correctly in my host.

Now I am looking for a way to execute the transformation in remote host(where carte in running). Please help me or redirect me to the proper documentation where I find the classes to use to accomplish this.

PDI Version - 5.0.1

Currently I am executing my Job as below

```
  try {
        if(jobDetails.getGraphlocation()!=null)
        {
            KettleEnvironment.init();
            JobMeta jobMeta = new JobMeta(jobDetails.getGraphlocation(), null);

            for( String s : jobDetails.getArguments() )
            {
                String[] splitString = s.split("\\=");
                if(splitString.length==2)
                {
                    jobMeta.setParameterValue(splitString[0], splitString[1]);

                }
                else
                    System.err.println("Parameter should be of the form - name=value");
            }

            Job job = new Job(null, jobMeta);
            job.setLogLevel(LogLevel.valueOf(jobDetails.getLoglevel().toString()));

            job.start();
            job.waitUntilFinished();
            if (job.getErrors()!=0) {
                System.out.println("Error encountered!");
            }   
        }
```

The above code is able to execute the Job where ever I am running it. But I want to execute it in slave server by just passing the carte username,password ans server IP address.

Answer (score 1):

you can do it through spoon by registering the carte server, or you can do it in a job by specifying the name and port of the carte server in the actual job/transformation step.  i.e. you can create a launcher which just has start, job ( pointing at carte server ), success steps.

Comment: Thanks for reply. I want to execute already existing Transformation/Job using Java API(By creating my own jar) as I have cannot access spoon. Please seen my edit.

Comment: Ah ok. Well Carte is just a webservice, so you could just call that direct telling it which transformation to run. Or you execute an existing transformation which launches your job on the remote server.

Comment: `so you could just call that direct telling it which transformation to run ` is there any documentation or can you  please let me know where I can find the suitable classes used to implement that? I have gone through all the issues related to this in Pentaho forums but found myself helpless :(